# questions related to connected set, smooth simple curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have following questions that I struggle with.

1. Prove that the boundary of any connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a simple curve, or give a counter example.
2. Prove that if $C$ is a smooth simple curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then its complement $\mathbb{R}^2 - C$ is a union of two connected open sets, exactly one of which is bounded, or find a counter example.

Need help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both false.

1) Consider the complement of a two-point set.

2) Let $C$ be a semicircle.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question. What is the boundary of two points set??